# replace all occurrences of . for normalization

Tags: java, regex

Say I have the string "foo/./bar" then it should be normalized to "foo/bar".
I tried doing this using the following regex:

```
String result = filePath.replaceAll("\\./", "");
```

but it didn't work out for me.. any idea?

Comment: Why notjust  filePath.replaceAll("/./", "/") ?

Comment: It should work. I don't see any error.

Comment: @Vash what if I had something like /far/bar/. what should that be normalized to?

Comment: also what if it is ./a/b/c/. it should then be /a/b/c

Comment: ./a is absolutely not the same as /a

Comment: It works for me. `System.out.println( "foo/./bar".replaceAll("\\./", "") );` prints out `foo/bar`.

Comment: @biziclop it needs to cover all the possible cases

Comment: is /a/b/c/. te same as /a/b/c?

Comment: @xonegirlz It would help if you clarified this in the question then. But if you want it to cover every case, do a second replaceAll, but this time with `"/\\."`. Alternatively, you can do `replaceAll( "(\\./)|(/\\.)", "" )`. This also demonstrates why it's often a better idea not to use regexps. You might score brownie points in your interview if you mention this.

Comment: I am just confused what ./a/b/c should be normalized to as the rule says to basically remove all . segments.. in this case , I don't think I should right?

Comment: `./a/b/c` is `a/b/c` and so is `a/b/c/.`

Answer (score 0):

In Java 7 there are built-in methods for this in the [`Path`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#normalize%28%29) class. (If you're not using Java 7, then sorry.)

Either way, regexps are probably not the best way to implement path normalisation. It's a lot easier to do a split and then add the path elements to a stack, adding nothing when the element is `.` and popping  if it's `..`.

Comment: Hmm, drive-by downvoting. At least give me some indication as to why do you think my answer is wrong, how am I going to learn otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you want is to normalize a Windows filepath, not just to remove periods (in your example, you would have to remove a period and the following slash). So, why not use [java.nio.Path](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html)?

```
Path path = Paths.get(unnormalizedPath);
Path normalized = path.normalize();
```

Or with pre-Java7, you can do

```
new File(unnormalizedPath).getCanonicalPath();
```

Comment: @xonegirlz: So it's homework? If so, please add the 'homework' tag to your question.

Comment: @home absolutely not a homrwork, I am just trying to practice my regex for an interview

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
System.out.println("./a/./b/c/."
                    .replaceAll("/[.]/|^[.]/","/")
                    .replaceAll("/[.]",""));
```

Output

```
/a/b/c
```